# Animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation

How to animate a div into determinated coordenades X and Y and choose the velocity with JavaScript?

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Animation</title>
    </head>

<body>

   <div id="img"><img src="image"</div>

    <form id="xy">
        X<input type="text" id="X"><br>
        Y<input type="text" id="Y"><br>
        V<input type="text" id="V"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Start">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving enough detail, so I can only suggest something quick and fun using CSS transitions. Check it out.

```js
var image = document.querySelector('#img');

document.querySelector('#xy [type=button]').onclick = function() {
    
    var x = document.querySelector('#X').value,
        y = document.querySelector('#Y').value,
        v = document.querySelector('#V').value;
    
    image.style.transitionDuration = v + 's';
    image.style.left = x + 'px';
    image.style.top = y + 'px';
};
```

```css
#img {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    left: 200px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="xy">
    X <input type="number" id="X" value="100" step="10"><br>
    Y <input type="number" id="Y" value="100" step="10"><br>
    V <input type="number" id="V" value="1" step="0.1"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Start">
</form>
    
<div id="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/100"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how advanced the animation is. If the animation includes user-functions, such as clicking or typing, JavaScript is needed. But otherwise, I believe you will need to use CSS3, aka Cascade Style Sheet, for animating. Here's a handy site for learning that; plus other languages too!

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp

c: